# How to make a graph using certain rows in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have an excel spreadsheet with around 500,000 rows of data, and Microsoft Excel can only have up to 32,000 rows, so I used a random number generator to generate 32,000 random numbers from 1 to 500,000. What would be the easiest way for me to create a graph using only the rows corresponding to the 32,000 random numbers I generated?

I definitely do not want to delete every row except the 32,000 I want manually...

Comment: Say your random numbers are in column E. A new column with the formula `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(),E$1:E$32000,0),2,1)` filled down to your last row will mark the rows that match your random numbers with a 1 and others with 2. Then you can sort all your data ascending on the column containing the 1s and 2s. The data you want to graph will then be in the first 32,000 rows, so you won't need to delete any rows if you don't want to. Create the graph by selecting the first, say, 10 rows. Then edit the data ranges (under Format>Data Series...) and change $B1:$B$10 (for example) to $B1:$B$32000.

Comment: Just opened Excel and it shows 1048576 rows so enough for your 500000 rows of data...

Comment: @SolarMike, for charting, the maximum data points is limited by available memory, so that may be where the 32K comes from.  Excel 2007 had a hard limit of 32,000 for 2D charts.  Useful reference for all of the limits applicable to different versions of Excel: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013

Comment: @Bandersnatch, go for it and post that as an answer.  BTW, if you include an example, you don't need to show all 500,000 or 32,000 rows.  :-)

Comment: Gee thanks, @fix.  :-D   OK, I guess I will.  For some reason, I quit caring about points when I hit 1K.  But it would be good to have it in an answer for posterity's sake, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, @SolarMike, I tried to find a reference for the limit too.  Found conflicting statements.  But a graph with 500k data points is sort of overkill anyway.  Even 32k.  Im trying to imagine what it would look like.  If the data symbol is only one pixel in diameter, it'll still be just a schmear of color. :-) Maybe the OP will post the final graph.

Comment: BTW, while looking for this limit, I saw a post by teylyn on some other site explaining that the limit is *per series*.  So if you **really** needed more data points, you could plot the next 32k as a second series, etc.

Comment: Another thought - there will be less than 32,000 data points because there will be duplicates among the random numbers and a given row number will only be marked once, even though there might be multiple occurrences of its number in the list of randoms.

Comment: @Bandersnatch I generated 32,000 random numbers without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Say your random numbers are in column E.  Then a new column with the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(),E$1:E$32000,0)),2,1)
```

filled down to your last row, will mark the rows that match your random numbers with a 1 and all others with 2.

Then you can sort all your data (ascending) on the column containing the 1s and 2s. The data you want to graph will then be in the first 32,000 rows, so you won't need to delete any rows if you don't want to.

Create the graph by selecting the first, say, 10 rows. Then edit the data ranges (under Chart > Source Data...) and change $B$1:$B$10 (for example) to $B$1:$B$32000.

EDIT: I'm glad I tested this.  The ascending sort works correctly, but the column with the 1s and 2s is then recalculated, which is kind of confusing.  If you want to see the original 1s and 2s, copy the column and use Paste Special > Values, to keep the numbers from changing.  Presumably, you had to do this with the random numbers also, to prevent them from being recalculated.

How the formula works: Match() tries to find the current row number in the list of random numbers. If it can't find a match, it returns the #N/A error, which makes ISERROR() True, so the IF() returns 2 as a result.  If a match *is* found, MATCH() returns a number and ISERROR() returns False, so the IF() returns 1.

Comment: Even though you don't care about the points, we need to encourage other users to test their answers, so sorry, I'm going to have to upvote this.  :-)

Comment: I don't have the random numbers in a column, instead I have them in a list separated by commas, is there any way I could work with that?

Comment: Unless it could work with all the numbers in one cell...

Comment: Where is the list, maybe in a text or CSV file?